# can't receive the message.content with discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello I began a discord bot but I can't give the message's content. I managed to get all the other things about message but the content return nothing. here is the code(ps: sorry if my english isn't very good, i'm French)  :

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message: discord.message.Message):
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        print(message.id)
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
            print('ok')
            await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message))


defIntents = discord.Intents.default()
defIntents.members = True
client = MyClient(intents=defIntents)
client.run('token')
```

Comment: Please re-generate your discord token. The client.run token is secret and should not be shared with anyone. There are probably edits to remove it but you need to remove it from your question immediately so your bot is not compromised.

Comment: @EthanR      thank you i completely forgot to replace the token...

Comment: You need to regenerate your discord bot token immediately, it's available in your edit history.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable the `Message Content Intent` of your application from [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and in your code you have to set the `message_content` intent to True like this.

```py
defIntents = discord.Intents.default()
defIntents.members = True
defIntents.message_content = True
client = MyClient(intents=defIntents)
```